# Deprioritize BitTorrent traffic

Tags: router, bittorrent, qos

I'm sure the question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it for myself; my Google-fu eludes me.

My router, the Linksys E2000, does a decent job at being reasonable about prioritizing some sorts of traffic above BitTorrent traffic (there isn't too much interruption to port 80, 443, or 22 traffic, the ones I use most often). But other ports get pummeled. For instance, 3000 (which I use for local Rails testing) becomes almost entirely non-functioning. Xbox Live traffic (not sure about the ports, but they are in the >1000 range) doesn't do well either.

So I'm wondering how to ensure that XBL and local Rails testing maintain strong service while BitTorrent is going. Is it enough that I turn up the QoS on their associated ports to high? It doesn't seem to be as effective as when BitTorrent isn't running at all (I don't know if there's a way to deprioritize BitTorrent traffic).

Comment: There is, but you seem to have already found it - QoS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bittorrent plays hell with some router Nat tables (NAT flooding), can you throttle your BT bandwidth?. I have always had issues when jammin bittorrent traffic to/from my PC, some routers do better than others. Some bittorrent clients can be configured to limit outbound connection attemps globally, sometimes this helps.

Have you tried other ports in your client for your BT traffic? You should use ports in this range 49160-65534

.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the bit torrent. Try limiting how many concurrent sessions are allowed.  If you are not controlling the BT traffic to my understanding there is very little you can do.