# DI-524UP will become deadly slow when downloading torrents

Tags: router, performance, bittorrent

I have a DI-524UP router that shares internet to two notebooks at home via wireless and a desktop via wired collection. It will become barely available/pingable via wireless when I download torrents on a desktop computer. Even when I limit download speed to 20% or less of available bandwidth - it must be something else, not the speed that causes the issue. I've tried limiting number of active connections and stuff but it will still not cure.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: See my answer here, different question but may be helpful...http://superuser.com/questions/229158/deprioritize-bittorrent-traffic

Comment: From personal experience with this router, I'd suggest double-checking that it's running the latest firmware and that the wireless mode setting is "G Mode", not "Mix Mode", if both notebooks have 802.11g-compatible wireless cards. Besides that, what torrent client are you using? What's the limit on active connections?

Comment: Tait, it is running the latest firmware, although it's quite old - like may 2008 or similar (can't check from work). I run uTorrent from the wired box and limit it to 50 active connections per torrent and 200 global. I've disabled pretty much everything I could disable in uTorrent but that didn't help a whole lot.

Comment: I've tried setting QoC on the router to favour 80 port - however, lots of DNS (unable to resolve) pop up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Right now this answer is diagnostic only: if the first part is accurate, I'm planning to edit this with a solution.)

It seems likely that the NAT table is filling up; the DI-524 only has about 8 MB of memory, so the NAT table is relatively small. Though torrenting is probably what's causing your problems, torrenting may actually just aggravate an underlying condition.

To check if torrenting is clogging the NAT table:

1. **Get a baseline of NAT table entries.**
  Download
  `http://<your router's IP address>/natlist.txt`
  and save it as
  `natlist-baseline.txt`
  . This file will serve as a point of comparision later on.
2. **Restart the router.**
  It's easier to test with a blank slate.
3. **Connect two machines to the network - one with a wired connection, the other wirelessly.**
4. **Enable logging on the router.**
  Use the wired machine to log into the router's web administration interface at
  `http://<your router's IP address>/`
  . Go to Status -> Log -> Log Settings, and make sure that "Dropped Packets" is checked. Go back to Status -> Log and remove all the current log entries by clicking "Clear".
5. **Stress the router until it's unresponsive to the wireless machine.**
  On the wireless machine, ping the router continuously, so it'll be obvious when the router is unresponsive. On the wired machine, find an active torrent that is likely to cause the router to seize up (an Ubuntu distribution works well) and begin torrenting. You can stop torrenting once the router is unresponsive.
6. **Check the router's log.**
  Use the wired machine to log into the router's web administration interface. Go to Status -> Log and look through all the log entries. Any "Out of NAT buffer" messages indicate that the router is filling up its NAT table.
7. **Get NAT table entries again.**
  Download
  `http://<your router's IP address>/natlist.txt`
  and save it as
  `natlist-post-test.txt`
  .
8. **Restart the router (or wait about 15 min.) to clear the NAT table.**

If you saw "Out of NAT buffer" messages in step 6, it's time to compare the two files you've downloaded. Otherwise, the NAT table probably isn't your issue — sorry.

The `natlist-baseline.txt` and `natlist-post-test.txt` files are plain-text dumps of the NAT table and some associated diagnostics. Right now we're just interested in measuring the ratio between a typical number of NAT entries (the baseline) and the maximum possible number of NAT entries (the post-test). In each file, find the line that looks like

```
 total entries = <some number>
```

and divide the number in the baseline file by the number in the post-test file. If the ratio is much above 0.5, torrenting might not be the only issue at hand.

Comment: there is no /natlist.txt on my DI-524

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if the file is case-sensitive; does your router have a /NATLIST.TXT or /CHKLST.TXT?